# Android Implicit Broadcast Exceptions

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast

Android [developer portal](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcast-exceptions) states broadcasts which can be registered in manifest itself, but it gives a caution as under

> Even though these implicit broadcasts still work in the background,
> you should avoid registering listeners for them.

One such broadcast which is exempted is as under:

> ACTION_LOCKED_BOOT_COMPLETED, ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED
> Exempted because
> these broadcasts are only sent only once, at first boot, and many apps
> need to receive this broadcast to schedule jobs, alarms, and so forth.

If we should avoid registering them (as per the above caution), then what is the right approach for ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED ?

**Use case:** Sync data with the server and show a notification to user (if any)

Answer (score 0):

If you need your app started at boot time, the only way to do this is to have a manifest-registered `BroadcastReceiver`.

Comment: yes, but Android 8+ doesn't allow the activity to be launched from the boot receiver

Comment: Correct. You cannot start an `Activity`. Instead you post a `Notification` and the user can tap on the `Notification` to launch the `Activity`.

Comment: Yes, true. For this in Android 8+, there is a need to create a notification channel before posting a notification